# You have played with me before -- haven't you?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> In many ways, I am special.
>
> But I am boring next to the Cross.
>
> Knock the Cross down, and there's nothing -- not a single thing -- that I can't eviscerate.
>
> Play with me, play with my friends, be *true* to us, and we will bring you things you never knew were possible.
>
> But play nice!
>
> If you abuse *me*, I will blow you, I will blow your mind, and I will blow your universe -- somewhere far, far away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> $0$
>  $0 + $Anything is Anything
>  $0 \times$Anything is $0$
>  Numbers are cool.
>  Anything$\div 0$ is weird and $0$ and $\infty$ interact in fun ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> Spirit.

It fears cross.

Without cross, it can do anything.

With Ouija board, one can play and interact with them.

But if you abuse them, you'd wish you shouldn't have done that.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please remember to hide your answers in spoilers. For more info, take the tour!